# How to fix wsl catastrophic error after expand vdisk maximum

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

My wsl had 256GB diskspace, and I tried to expand it to 512GB following the official instructions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/vhd-size

After completing steps 1-5, at step 6, the wsl can't be launched any more. The error message just says "catastrophic error" without any other hints. None of the solutions in the wsl GitHub repo helps: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5092

How can we fix this error, or revert the diskpart operation to go back to the previous normal state?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why not remove the WSL distribution and start a new one?

Comment: @harrymc Presumably, if there was the need to expand it above 256GB, then the distribution disk probably already had somewhere over 200GB in use.  That's a lot of destroyed data if that's the case.  :-(

Comment: The link you followed finishes by the warning: "We recommend that you do not modify, move, or access the WSL related files located inside of your AppData folder using Windows tools or editors". A pity it wasn't put at the beginning of the article.

Comment: Note2: I just now repeated the manipulation as described in the article and everything went fine. At what stage exactly did it go wrong for you?

Comment: @harrymc I think that warning (at least much of the wording) is left over from [this concept](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/) and someone in the doc team at Microsoft placed it in a weird (not *quite* applicable) place.  The original warning really only applied to WSL1.  Otherwise that entire document would be contrary do that advice.  That said, I would never recommend doing a resize without a backup in place, along with a `wsl --shutdown`.  The entire Microsoft doc there seems to be "naïve" in this regard.

Comment: Is this Windows 10 or 11?  Your recovery options *might* be different depending on whether or not you can try to `wsl --mount` the vhdx in a new distribution -- That option would only be available in Windows 11.

Comment: I followed the official instructions rigorously, without any other operations. I tried to expand to 512GB and there was sufficient space left on my PC. I used Windows 11

Comment: When I installed the wsl, the OS was Windows 10. I recently upgraded to Windows 11.